# Give other people access to my development team in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I have a "single member" Apple Membership profile, and one of the developers I work with needs access to my development team to test the app he's building on his device (Xcode won't allow him to build the app without one). How can I give him access to the development team without having to give him the login credentials of my account?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you have a individual account, you don't have any development team on your own and hence cannot invite a collegue in your not existing team. To own a team, your membership's `Entity type` must be `Company / Organization` . You can see it at https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/. 
To update your entity type, you'll have to provide some documents about your company. 
At the moment there is no simple procedure in the dashboard as "click this button, upload some documents and magic you're now Company", you'll have to ask directly to Apple support (a colleague have done this for 2 different accounts)

More infos here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

Comment: You were faster than me for 19 seconds, well done ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you have registered your account with type Company / Organization, go to manu People and invite a new user.

If you have registered your account as Individual, you are out of luck I think since this type of account is not able to invite users and the People menu entry does not exist.