# How do I not commit the development team lines in project.pbxproj without deselecting those lines manually?

Tags: xcode, git

I am collaborating with my friend on an iOS app. We use different Apple IDs in our Xcodes, so in "Signing and Capabilities" tab of project settings, we select different teams in the "Team" field:

[image]

From my observation, changing this affects the `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file, which stores the file references that the Xcode project has, in addition to the "Team". Here's a snippet of what is changed:

```
        buildSettings = {
            ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
            ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GLOBAL_ACCENT_COLOR_NAME = AccentColor;
            CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
            DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = <my team ID>; /* this is changed */
            INFOPLIST_FILE = MyProject/Info.plist;
            LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "@executable_path/Frameworks",
            );
            PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = io.github.sweeper777.MyApp;
            PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
            SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
            TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1;
        };
```

The problem arises, when one of us commits this file and the other person pulls. The "puller" will now have the "Team" set to something invalid. When this person then tries to run the app on a real device, there will be code signing errors for obvious reasons. To solve this, this person must tediously go through all the targets that we have, and set each "Team" to their own team.

How can we make it so that on each person's computer, the "Team" stays the same after pulling, but any other changes to `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` is applied?

Remarks:

- Putting the entire `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` in `.gitignore` doesn't work, because that would ignore every other change to it. Adding a new file to the project, for example, also changes `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`, and we want to be able to pull that change.
- Manually deselecting the lines that say "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = ..." when committing is as tedious as reselecting the correct team every time, so that's not a solution.
- I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of). Apparently, I can configure git to run `sed` before `git checkout` and `git add`. However, that answer seems ignore the line by deleting it completely. This means that my friend, when he pulls, would *still* have to reselect the correct team. What I want is the kind of "ignore" that simply *stops tracking* that line. That is, if there is a local version of that line, use that.
- I am also aware that this all wouldn't be a problem if we are on the same team. But if I understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654366/give-other-people-access-to-my-development-team-in-xcode) correctly, I can't have multiple people on my team unless I have a Company account, and not only can I not afford that, I don't own a Company.

Comment: What an annoyance. However, I'm having a little trouble seeing why replacing all occurrences of `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = WHATEVER;` in that file with the correct value is anything more than a simple one-liner script. Configuration scripts are a common need whenever you're doing shared dev.

Comment: I was thinking that there is some way to do this in Xcode, because in my mind this should be a common problem. I don't know how to use `sed` at all (I didn't even know it existed before finding the linked question), so the idea that it can be done in a one-liner script didn't occur to me, and that made me go in the wrong direction, thinking about how to not track it, or put it in another file instead. @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Xcode itself and do not know how to smuggle Git hooks and scripts past the Xcode interface, so you'll need more than just this answer.  But you mention `sed` in comments, and given your proposed file format, that may well be the way to go:

> ```
>    buildSettings = {
>        ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
>        ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GLOBAL_ACCENT_COLOR_NAME = AccentColor;
>        CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
>        DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = <my team ID>; /* this is changed */
>        INFOPLIST_FILE = MyProject/Info.plist;
>        LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
>            "$(inherited)",
>            "@executable_path/Frameworks",
>        );
>        PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = io.github.sweeper777.MyApp;
>        PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
>        SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
>        TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1;
>    };
> ```

Git has the ability to run what it calls *clean* and *smudge* filters.  These can be used to run any arbitrary program you like, including `sed`, the "stream editor", which is particularly good at making single-line changes based on [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matches.

There is another method that may also work, and may "play better" with Xcode, or may play worse.  I'll go over that too, after covering clean and smudge filters.

Before we dive into writing clean and smudge filters, and using them from Git—you'll need to know all of these details as you will have to write your own custom filters—we should start with a simple fact about Git commits: **No part of any commit can ever be changed.**  Once you make a commit, the stuff that's *inside* the commit—the stored data in all of its files—is the way it is, forever.  So these filters have to work within that system.  Remember that, as it will help with understanding what we're doing.

#### How Git makes and stores *objects*

The files inside a commit are not *files*, exactly: they're not the same thing as files in your file system, at least.  Instead, they are what Git calls *objects*, specifically *blob objects*.  A blob object holds the file's data; other objects hold the file's name; and commit objects collect everything together to be used all at once.  There's one more internal object type for annotated tags but we'll stop here as we're really only interested in the blob-object part.

When Git *extracts* a commit, it reads the internal blob objects and runs them through internal code to decompress and format them into regular files.  This can include doing end-of-line hacking (turning LFs into CRLFs) if desired.  Normally, all this happens entirely inside Git, and the end result is that Git writes out an ordinary everyday file for you to use.  This ordinary file is what you will work on / with, in Xcode or any other editor and compiler system and so on.  These ordinary files are in your *working tree*.

After you've extracted some commit, you'll do some work on it, by changing some or all of the files *in* your working tree, to achieve whatever result you wanted.  This can include changing the `buildSettings`, editing Swift code, editing <s>Objectionable-C</s> Objective-C code, and so on.  You might add all-new files to the working tree, some of which you never commit at all (you can help make sure this never happens by listing such files in `.gitignore`).

Eventually, though, you'd like to *commit* the updated code.  To do so, you must run `git add`, or maybe have your IDE run `git add` for you (perhaps Xcode has clicky buttons to do this).  This invokes code in Git that *converts the working tree file(s) back to internal blob objects* if and as needed.

Again, normally this is all handled entirely inside of Git.  Git will read the working tree file, maybe do CRLF-to-LF-only changes, compress the text, search for duplicate objects, and do all the other complicated things necessary to *prepare* the file, so that it is ready to be committed.  The resulting data need not match what's in your working tree at all: it just has to be something that, when Git later goes to *extract* the file, *produces* what you will need in your working tree.

#### Clean and smudge filters

This is where these clean and smudge filters come in.  I said, above, that normally, Git does the extraction and insertion all on its own.  For binary files, the only thing Git does here is apply lossless compression.<sup>1</sup>  For text files, Git can do CRLF/LF substitutions as well.  But what if you'd like to do *your own* operations?

You can: Git will let you do whatever you want during the *extract* process with a *smudge filter*, and will let you do whatever you want during the *compress* process with a *clean filter*.  The clean filter replaces the in-file data, using a stream-edit type process,<sup>2</sup> and then Git does its CRLF hacking if any and compressing on the "cleaned" data.  The smudge filter replaces the decompressed, post-CRLF-hacking data coming *out* of Git with the data that should go into the working tree.

Hence you can write, as your clean filter, a sed script of the form:

```
s/DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = .*;/DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = DEVTEAMTEMPLATE;/
```

With that as the entire sed script, what `sed` will do is edit the incoming data stream and replace any actual development team text with the word `DEVTEAMTEMPLATE`.

Your *smudge* filter has to work slightly harder: it must find the template line and adjust it so that it contains the *correct* team ID.  Where will you *get* the correct team ID?  That's up to you: perhaps you can store it in a file in your home directory, or in a file that you create in the working tree but never commit in Git.  You'll have to write this one or two or however-many-liner `sed` and/or shell script yourself.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are multiple phases of compression; `git add` does just one, and `git checkout` undoes all—including reading from "pack" files—as needed.  The deeper level of compression, using [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) techniques, is entirely invisible at the "object" level, so nobody ever really has to think about it.

<sup>2</sup>With the advent of Git-LFS, Git gained the ability to run *long-lived filters*.  Before that, Git always used simple stream filtering.  The stream filtering is easier to understand, but is less efficient for doing en-masse operations on many files.  Here, we're only interested in one file per repository anyway, so there's no need to go into the fancier long-lived filter details.

---

#### Defining clean and smudge filters

The tricky part here, with Git, is that you must *define* the filters in one place—in `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `.git/config`, for instance—and then tell Git to *invoke* them from another place, using the `.gitattributes` file.  This is described in [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).  This documentation is pretty thorough, so read it.  You can ignore all the long-running filter discussion, as noted above.  I will quote one bit from the documentation here for emphasis, though, and expound on it:

> Note that "%f" is the name of the path that is being worked on. Depending on the version that is being filtered, the corresponding file on disk may not exist, or may have different contents. So, smudge and clean commands should not try to access the file on disk, but only act as filters on the content provided to them on standard input.

When Git is running the smudge filter, it:

- has opened some internal object (which may or may not be packed);
- has decompressed it, or is in the process of decompressing it, and pumped / is-pumping out the data; and
- this data is being fed *to* your filter, but *is not written out to any file anywhere*.

Your filter can use `%f` to know the name of the target output file, but the data *are not in that file yet*.  The data bytes are only in some OS-level pipes or sockets or whatever your OS uses for connecting the output of one program (Git's internal decompressors) to another (your filter).  Your smudge filter must *read its standard input* to get the data, and *write the smudged data to standard output* so that Git can read it (if necessary) and/or redirect that output to the correct file.  **Do not attempt to open the file by name!**

(The same holds for the clean filter, except that in many cases, the input to your filter *is* just the raw data already in the file, so that opening the file and reading it mostly works.  So this can mislead you, if you do your tests using a clean filter.)

Note that you can implement this scheme without a clean filter at all: your smudge filter can replace whatever is in the committed file even if it's a real team ID, rather than just a template.  If you choose to do this, however, you'll "see" the team ID changing every time a different team-ID commits the file.  The nice thing about using the clean filter is that once the committed copies of the file use the template line, every future cleaned file also uses the template line, so that it never changes.

#### Alternative: a template *file*

In general, it's unwise to commit actual configurations.  Clean and smudge tricks can work, but they can only go so far: this particular file format works well because the change you want made is on a single line, and Git itself shows you file changes on a line-by-line basis, and `sed` works well with line-oriented input, and so on.

A lot of configuration files, though, wind up storing at least slightly-sensitive data, or perhaps very-sensitive data such as cleartext passwords.  **Such files should not be stored in Git at all** if at all possible.  Instead, you would store a *template* file in Git.

In this case, for instance, instead of storing `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`, you might have Git store `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.template`.  This file would have template-ized contents.  When you clone and check out the repository, you'd subsequently *copy* the template file into place and do any required adjustments.

Should the `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file itself need to change, e.g., to acquire a new `SWIFT_VERSION` setting, you'd instead edit the *template* file, add that to Git, and commit.  You would then use the usual "convert template to mine" process, or manually update the `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file.  Since this file is never committed—and is listed in `.gitignore`—it never goes into any commit and you never have to worry about collisions within it.  Only the *template* file goes into Git.

Comment: Hmm, the part about "where to store the filters" gave me an idea. If it can be stored in `$HOME/.gitconfig` (I'm guessing that's what `git config --global` does?), then the filters won't be tracked because it's not in the repo folder. This means that me and my friends can use different filters - my filter would set it to my team ID when smudging, and his will set it to his team ID.

Comment: If (big if) you're dedicated to using Git here (which you will be with clean/smudge tricks), you could store your team ID as a `git config --global` setting, yes. If you want to use a template file, you won't be Git-dependent and that's probably not a good idea. Not knowing how people use Xcode I'm not willing to make any particular suggestions, though.

Comment: `clean and smudge filters` would work well in this case since Dev Team isn't a critical piece of info but seems scary if you want to use it with passwords/tokens since it's easy to forget to set up the global config for it in `git`. I like the `template` idea more but also has a drawback since all your changes in the file `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` won't be committed and needs always to keep the template in sync. Your ideas are really cool just trying to make some notices for the guys who gonna pick some of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution to this problem on macOS, in case someone in need stumbles upon this question like I did :-)

Like you, I'm collaborating with a friend on an app, but this time on macOS. This is a bit simpler because you can typically run the app locally without signing it, as long as you don't need some of the more advanced app capabilities. In the `project.pbxproj` file I therefore have `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = ""`, allowing both of us to build and run the app.

We only need proper code signing when we export the final app for distribution. For this we include an `ExportOptions.plist` with the appropriate team ID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>developer-id</string>
        <key>teamID</key>
        <string>XXXXXXXXXX</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I then added a post-action script to the Archive step, as explained in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow/customizing_the_xcode_archive_process). This re-signs the app based on the team ID in the export options, puts it in a disk image and notarizes it, essentially outside of the Xcode GUI, which is why you can get away with this.

We commit `ExportOptions.plist` to the repository but that's also optional.

---

In case you are interested, here is my export script based on the sample script in the Apple docs and adapted according to Quinn's [excellent advice](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701581) so that it also signs and staples the disk image:

```bash
# The bulk of this script originates from this example:
#
# https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow/customizing_the_xcode_archive_process
#
# Another very helpful post is https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701581

# notarytool credentials.
# AC_PASSWORD is the name of the keychain item created with `notarytool store-credentials`.
# Grant keychain access to Xcode if prompted by Xcode.
AC_PASSWORD="Notary Service"

# Do all of the work in a subdirectory of /tmp, and use a
# unique ID so that there's no collision with previous builds.
EXPORT_UUID=`uuidgen`
EXPORT_PATH="/tmp/$PRODUCT_NAME-$EXPORT_UUID/"
APP_PATH="$EXPORT_PATH/$PRODUCT_NAME.app"
DMG_PATH="$EXPORT_PATH/$PRODUCT_NAME.dmg"

mkdir -p "$EXPORT_PATH"

# Xcode doesn't show run script errors in build log.
exec > "$EXPORT_PATH/Xcode run script.log" 2>&1

# Use osascript(1) to present notification banners; otherwise
# there's no progress indication until the script finishes.
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'display notification "Exporting application archive…" with title "Submitting app for notarization"'

# Ask xcodebuild(1) to export the app. Use the export options
# from a previous manual export that used a Developer ID.
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "$ARCHIVE_PATH" -exportOptionsPlist "$SRCROOT/ExportOptions.plist" -exportPath "$EXPORT_PATH"

osascript -e 'display notification "Creating UDIF Disk Image…" with title "Submitting app for notarization"'

cd "$EXPORT_PATH/"
mkdir "$PRODUCT_NAME"
mv -v "$APP_PATH" "$PRODUCT_NAME"

# Create a UDIF-format read-only zip-compressed disk image (type UDZO).
# The original sample script used UDBZ, which is unnecessarily read-write and also deprecated according to hdiutil's man page.
/usr/bin/hdiutil create -srcfolder "$PRODUCT_NAME" -format UDZO "$DMG_PATH"

# DEVELOPER_TEAM is unset, so look for Team ID in export options
TEAM_ID=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :teamID" "$SRCROOT/ExportOptions.plist"`
# Find the relevant Developer ID identity used to sign the app.
# This assumes that the relevant certificate appears exactly once in the Keychain.
IDENTITY=`/usr/bin/security find-identity -v -p codesigning | grep "Developer ID Application" | grep $TEAM_ID | sed -E 's/.+"(.+)"/\1/'`

# Sign the disk image with the same certificate used for the app inside
/usr/bin/codesign -vvv -s "$IDENTITY" --timestamp -i "$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" "$DMG_PATH"  

osascript -e 'display notification "Submitting UDIF Disk Image for notarization…" with title "Submitting app for notarization"'

# Submit the finished deliverables for notarization.
# Wait up to 2 hours for a response.
# Use verbose logging in order to file feedback if an error occurs.
"$DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR/notarytool" submit -p "$AC_PASSWORD" --verbose "$DMG_PATH" --wait --timeout 2h --no-progress --output-format plist > "NotarizationResponse.plist"

return_code=$?

if [ $return_code -eq 0 ]; then

# Success!
message=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :message" "NotarizationResponse.plist"`
status=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :status" "NotarizationResponse.plist"`

# Staple the notarization ticket to the disk image to allow offline installation of the app
"$DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR/stapler" staple -v "$DMG_PATH"

else
message="An Error Occurred."
status="Check Xcode log."
open "$EXPORT_PATH/Xcode run script.log"
fi

# Show and speak the final status.
osascript -e "on run(argv)" \
-e 'display notification item 1 of argv & " : " & item 2 of argv with title "Submitting app for notarization" sound name "Crystal"' \
-e 'set text item delimiters to ", "' \
-e "set args to argv as text" \
-e "say args" \
-e "delay 5" \
-e "end" \
-- "$message" "$status"

# Open the folder that was created, which also signals completion.
open "$EXPORT_PATH"
```